# AS3: FMS Live Stream: Pause/Resume?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-media-server

What is the proper way of **Pausing then Resuming** a LIVE Stream with AS3 (native code, no prebuilt player).

With the normal pause/resume methods - pause is working fine, but resume has no effect (video stays).

It works if I do a `netconnection.close()` and then call `play()` again - but this causes a long delay before the video plays again.

I tried another version with `seek(0)` before `pause()` and it also had no effect.

Any suggestions?
Thank you!

Comment: Which protocols are u using.. Multicast / RTMFP / RTMP .. Can u post the code so we could help ?

Comment: are you using live DVR, or just want to jump ahead back to live when resume is hit?

Comment: Have you tried calling `play()` instead of `resume()`?   resume doesn't apply to live streams (unless your using LiveDVR)

Comment: Thanks for your interest. We are using RTMP LiveStream, the source is a capturing card via an adobe media encoder.

Comment: yes, i tried play() - no effect. the only way it seems to work is to close() and reconnect to that stream. but this is a lengthy operation of cause...